# Savely load managed object with Uri

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift4

I'm working on a simple ToDo app and save the Uri of the currently selected `List` in the User Defaults so I can load the right one again when the app is launched the next time.

My problem is that even if I delete the corresponding `List` from its managed object context

`coordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: uri)`

returns a `NSManagedObjectID` which is a problem because `viewContext.object(with: listId)` then returns a faulted `List` which is not existing anymore.

```
func selectedList() -> List? {

    guard let uri = UserDefaults.standard.selectedListUri() else
    { print("Could not get Uri from User Defaults"); return nil }

    guard let coordinator = viewContext.persistentStoreCoordinator else
    { print("Store Coordinator is nil"); return nil }

    guard let listId = coordinator.managedObjectID(forURIRepresentation: uri) else
    { print("Store Coordinator could not get managedObjectID of the entity"); return nil }

    guard let list = viewContext.object(with: listId) as? List else
    { print("WARNING: Object for managedObjectID is not a *List*"); return nil }


    return list
}
```

I'm not sure if that is the intended behavior, but if so, is there a save way to check if the faulted List is valid?

I figured out I could do it the following way, put Im pretty sure this is not the intended behavior because the reference states that when the entity is non existent but the fault is fired an exception is raised.

> func object(with objectID: NSManagedObjectID) -> NSManagedObject
>
> This method always returns an object. The data in the persistent store represented by objectID is assumed to exist—if it does not, the returned object throws an exception when you access any property (that is, when the fault is fired).

However I can access the property `createdAt` and get nil returned although the property is non-optional, but no exception seems to be raised.

```
let createdAt = list.createdAt 
print(createdAt) /* Prints nil */
```

Comment: Why are you doing all this, storing an URI in UserDefaults etc? You say you have an simple app but this looks very complicated, do you have a local storage or a remote?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson 
I use it to save the 'state of the application', which in this case is saving the last selected list and load it again on startup. I think that would be a convenient experience.